# Compare activerecord results with sorted results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, rails-activerecord

I am writing a test in rspec to make sure a function is returning a correctly sorted result set. The test looks like this:

```
it 'returns matching accounts' do
  results = Account.search(<search conditions>)
  expect(results).to eq results.order(<order clause>)
end
```

The result sets appear to be equivalent, but the test still fails. The following test does pass:

```
it 'returns matching accounts' do
  results = Account.search(<search conditions>)
  expect(results.map &:id).to eq results.order(<order clause>).map &:id
end
```

I am satisfied that this test does what I need, but is there a better way to compare two ActiveRecord relations?

Comment: What is the error message for the first failure?

Answer (score 2):

`Account.search` probably doesn't return an array of accounts, but a [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html). When you call `order` on a relation it will return a different relation object and therefore not match.

On the other hand if you call an method on that relation that forces the relation to actually run the query against the database, then an array is returned. `map` is such a method, other might be `each`, `first`, `any?`, `load`, etc.

[`load`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load) seems to be a good choice to use, to force actually loading the records from the database:

```
it 'returns matching accounts' do
  results = Account.search(<search conditions>)
  expect(results.load).to eq results.order(<order clause>).load
end
```

Another option might be to compare the result against a array, that was sorted in Ruby instead of in the database. It depends on what you really want to test, if this is a better option:

```
it 'returns matching accounts' do
  results = Account.search(<search conditions>).load
  expect(results).to eq results.sort_by(&:attribute_to_sort_on)
end
```

Comment: `load` mysteriously worked with one test but not another. I ended up using `to_a` on the ActiveRecord relations to compare them. I had also tried an array sorted in Ruby, but that gave me a different order with 'equivalent' rows - not wrong, but not useful for comparison with the result from the database.